# web2py dal sql 'like' equivalent

Tags: web2py, data-access-layer

Hello everyone i'm wondering if there is a 'like' equivalent in web2py dal.

I would like to do something like this:

```
db().select(db.person.name like 'JA')
```

thank you very much for your help!

Jason

Answer (score 7):

just found my answer

```
db().select(db.person.name.like('JA%'))
```